# How to Lookup for the Values Of a Column on another Column and copy those rows wheret the value is found and create a new list

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, lookup

I have an Excel list that has around 100,000 customers. The list is organized this way: Account name, Customer Name, Account number, etc. I need to separate the Latin last names from the American ones. The thing is that the name and last name are on the same column.

I need to find out a way to to be able to select all rows that have the most common Latin last names that I have set on another Excel list so I can create a new list from that selection and separate the, Latin last names from the American ones.

Comment: That would be ideal if the list had 2 columns (Name and Last Name) But it only has one (Customer Name) where the name and last name are

Comment: The name and last name can be on the same column. For Example this is how the list is from column A to J. Account Name, Customer Name, Account Number, Utility, Service Street, Service Suite, Service City, Service State, Service Zip, Contact Number.  So for example on row 3 i have Juan Perez i need to be able to select the complete row were the Perez last name is, and do the same for all other rows that have the last names i have specified on another excel sheet

Comment: It sounds like you could create a second column to hold the last name, and use Text to Column, or perhaps a formula (`=Left(A1,search(" ",A1))...`)?

Comment: I can't seem to get Text to column to work properly. I can split the contnent from the Column to 2 new columns but all the names don't have the same length and some of them are cut of in the middle. How can i work around this?

Comment: Did you select deliminator with space or fixed width?  I'm guessing fixed width, when it should have been space delineated.

Comment: If you can add a column in the original data list, that would work well.  Then use the Find formula.  From there you could do vlookup on that column with the find results into another worksheet.

Comment: Going to try this. Sorry guys but i haven't used excel much

Comment: I managed to get it done. Some of the Customer Names have more than 1 Name or last name so i ended up with 4 more columns. So now i just need to search for all the last names i have specified on the other sheet and select all the rows that have those last names so i can cut it out and create the Spanish list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

First i had to use text to columns to separate names from last names, Delimited to spaces, I ended up with 4 or 6 columns.

Added a new sheet named "LastNames" with all the latin last names i could find.

I used this formula to match the last names with the ones i had on my newly created sheet: (B2 was my initial cell, Copied formulas for other cells)

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,LastNames!$A$1:$A$2666, 0)), 0, 1)
```

After this i used a simple SUM to find out which ones have the Last Names on my list, Then sort by the column with the SUM which outputs Yes or no.

The just used this to put all the names on the same column again:

```
=b2&" "&c2&" "&d2&" "&e2
```

Copy, paste as values and it's done. This took me a while to figure it out since i'm not used to use excel.